Haskell program not finding student in database despite correct ID
I'm encountering an issue with my Haskell program where it's unable to find a student in the database despite providing the correct student ID.
Details:
Objective: My program is designed to search for students in a database using their unique IDs.
Problem: When I provide the correct student ID as input, the search operation returns Nothing, indicating that the student was not found in the database.
Expected Behavior: I expect the program to find and display the details of the student with the provided ID from the database.
Troubleshooting: I've reviewed the code for the search operation and verified the format and contents of the input data (database.csv). However, I'm still unable to identify the root cause of the issue.
Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking assistance in troubleshooting this issue and determining why the program is unable to find the student despite the correct ID being provided. Any insights, suggestions, or debugging techniques would be greatly appreciated.
Here is Main.hs
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Options.Applicative
import Lib
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let options = info (helper <*> parseOptions)
        (fullDesc <> progDesc "Student Management System")
  command <- execParser options
  dataMaybe <- readData
  let enrollments = fromMaybe [] dataMaybe
  case command of
    SearchStudent searchId -> do
      let result = searchStudent searchId enrollments
      print result
    AddStudent name id -> do
      let updatedEnrollments = addStudent name id enrollments
      writeData updatedEnrollments
    AddModule code name -> do
      let updatedEnrollments = addModule code name enrollments
      writeData updatedEnrollments
    GenerateReport output -> do
      let report = generateReport enrollments
      writeFile output report


Here is Lib.hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib where

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TL
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.List (find)
import Options.Applicative

data Student = Student { studentName :: String, studentId :: Int } deriving (Show)
data Module = Module { moduleCode :: String, moduleName :: String } deriving (Show)
data Enrollment = Enrollment Student Module deriving (Show)

dataFile :: String
dataFile = "database.csv"

readData :: IO (Maybe [Enrollment])
readData = do
  content <- TL.readFile dataFile
  let lines = TL.lines content
  let parsedLines = map parseLine lines
  return $ sequence parsedLines

parseLine :: TL.Text -> Maybe Enrollment
parseLine line = do
  let fields = TL.splitOn "," line
  guard (length fields >= 4)
  let name = TL.unpack $ fields !! 0
  studentId <- readMaybe (TL.unpack (fields !! 1)) :: Maybe Int
  let moduleCode = TL.unpack $ fields !! 2
  let moduleName = TL.unpack $ fields !! 3
  return $ Enrollment (Student name studentId) (Module moduleCode moduleName)

writeData :: [Enrollment] -> IO ()
writeData enrollments = TL.writeFile dataFile (TL.unlines $ map formatEnrollment enrollments)

formatEnrollment :: Enrollment -> TL.Text
formatEnrollment (Enrollment (Student name id) (Module code moduleName)) = 
  TL.pack (name ++ "," ++ show id ++ "," ++ code ++ "," ++ moduleName)

data Command
  = SearchStudent Int
  | AddStudent String Int
  | AddModule String String
  | GenerateReport String

parseOptions :: Parser Command
parseOptions = subparser
  ( command "search" (info (SearchStudent <$> argument auto (metavar "ID")) (progDesc "Search student by ID"))
 <> command "add-student" (info (AddStudent <$> strArgument (metavar "NAME") <*> argument auto (metavar "ID")) (progDesc "Add a new student"))
 <> command "add-module" (info (AddModule <$> strArgument (metavar "CODE") <*> strArgument (metavar "NAME")) (progDesc "Add a new module"))
 <> command "report" (info (GenerateReport <$> strArgument (metavar "OUTPUT")) (progDesc "Generate report"))
  )

searchStudent :: Int -> [Enrollment] -> Maybe Enrollment
searchStudent id enrollments = find (\(Enrollment (Student _ sId) _) -> sId == id) enrollments

addStudent :: String -> Int -> [Enrollment] -> [Enrollment]
addStudent name id enrollments = Enrollment (Student name id) (Module "" "") : enrollments

addModule :: String -> String -> [Enrollment] -> [Enrollment]
addModule code name enrollments = Enrollment (Student "" 0) (Module code name) : enrollments

generateReport :: [Enrollment] -> String
generateReport enrollments = unlines (map show enrollments)


database.csv is an excel spreadsheet. Here is how it shows up on VS code
Student Name,Student ID,Module Code
Charlie,2004,1

Problem: When I provide the correct student ID as input (stack exec student-management-exe -- search 2004), the search operation returns Nothing, indicating that the student was not found in the database.
Expected Behavior: I expect the program to find and display the details of the student with the provided ID from the database.

Have you tried printing the database to see if it parses correctly?

Why guard (length fields >= 4) when your entries have 3 fields?

Do you know how to set up your VS Code project so that you can conveniently load it into GHCi and run functions interactively?  Are you able to "Run and Debug" your project under VS Code?
